# How to convert string into float value in the dataframe

Tags: python, azure, pandas, azure-machine-learning-service

We are facing an error when we have a column which have datatype as string and the value like 
col1  col2 
1      .89

So, when we are using

```
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):

    # Execution logic goes here
    print('Input pandas.DataFrame #1:')
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.kernel_approximation import RBFSampler
    x =dataframe1.iloc[:,2:1080]
    print x
    df1 = dataframe1[['colname']]

    change = np.array(df1)
    b = change.ravel()
    print b
    rbf_feature = RBFSampler(gamma=1, n_components=100,random_state=1)
    print rbf_feature
    print "test"
    X_features = rbf_feature.fit_transform(x)
```

After this we are getting error as cannt convert non int into type float

Answer (score 7):

Use [`astype(float)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas.Series.astype) e.g.:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(float)
```

or [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects):

```
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

Example:

```
In [379]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1.23', '0.123']})
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
a    2 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 32.0+ bytes
In [380]:

df['a'].astype(float)
Out[380]:
0    1.230
1    0.123
Name: a, dtype: float64

In [382]:

df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
a    2 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 32.0 bytes
```

**UPDATE**

If you're running version `0.17.0` or later then `convert_objects` has been replaced with the methods: [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas.to_numeric), [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime), and [`to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html) so instead of:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(float)
```

you can do:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'])
```

note that by default any non convertible values will raise an error, if you want these to be forced to `NaN` then do:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: invalid literal for float(): 0.00|                                                              when we have changed code this                                                                                                             x =dataframe1.iloc[:,2:100].astype(float) df1 = dataframe1[['StateCode']].asastype(float)

Comment: You have duff data, are you able to post raw input data into your question

Comment: @EdChum I have a followup question related to your code. I tried `df['a'].astype(float)`, which works, i.e., convert all of these 2 entries from string to float. However if I type `df['a'][1].astype(float)`, it gives me a AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'. Why it happens? the whole series can be converted but not each entry?

Comment: @ftxx because astype is a series method and not a method for str, it would fail even if it was an int. You're trying to call astype on a single str not a series